# JQuery, Bootstrap navs - how do I add prev/next buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap navs for my page and I want to add next and prev buttons to my tab content.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li class="active"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#randomtab">Randomtab</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="overview" class="tab-pane fade in active">

    <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Next</a>

  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  </div>
  <div id="randomtab" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function() {
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
    var x = $(event.target).text(); // active tab
    var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text(); // previous tab
    $(".act span").text(x);
    $(".prev span").text(y);
  });
});
```

I tried to add this JavaScript code but I don’t know how to write `a[href=(this).href]`

```
$(".tab-pane a").click(function() {
  $('a[href="(this.href)"]').tab('show'); //this row is wrong
});
$('.tab-pane a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
  var x = $(event.target).text(); // active tab
  var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text(); // previous tab
  $(".act span").text(x);
  $(".prev span").text(y);
});
```

This is my solution, maybe there is a better one but I don’t know...Thank you.

PS: Please leave comment below if you don’t understand my question, so I can edit this post.

**EDIT**

This is the working solution for bootstrap navs:

thanks to Arun P Johny

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li class="active"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#randomtab">Randomtab</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="overview" class="tab-pane fade in active">

    <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Next</a>

  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="tab-pane fade in active">

    <a href="#overview" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Prev</a>

    <a href="#randomtab" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Next</a>

  </div>
  <div id="randomtab" class="tab-pane fade in active">

    <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Prev</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-tabs a").click(function() {
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
    var x = $(event.target).text(); // active tab
    var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text(); // previous tab
    $(".act span").text(x);
    $(".prev span").text(y);
  });
  $(".tab-pane a").click(function() {
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
  });
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
    var x = $(event.target).text(); // active tab
    var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text(); // previous tab
    $(".act span").text(x);
    $(".prev span").text(y);
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('a[href="'+this.href+'"]').tab('show');`

Comment: Thanks, but my code doesnt work with this. This work: `$('a[href="#contact"]').tab('show');` but if i use your code it do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is `href` property will have absolute path so try

```
$('a[href="'+ $(this).attr('href')+'"]').tab('show');
```